# ajax call works in chrome and IE but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this simple form and the associated ajax call to a .php file.

The call works fine (i.e. i get back the results I want) when using IE or Chrome, but not with Firefox.

From what I see in Firefox debug is that the call to search.php is not properly executed (i.e. marked in red).

Could someone help me out?

Here is the form:

---

```
<form id="form_search" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="timeRange" value="24h">Last 24 hours</label></div>
    <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="timeRange" value="week">Last 7 days</label></div>
    <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="timeRange" value="month" checked="checked">Last 30 days</label></div>
    <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="timeRange" value="quarter">Last 3 months</label></div>
    <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="timeRange" value="semi">Last 6 months</label></div>
    <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="lang" value="english" checked="checked">English</label></div>
    <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="lang" value="french">French</label></div>
    <div class="radio disabled"><label><input type="radio" name="lang" value="norwegian" disabled>Norwegian</label></div>
    <div class="radio disabled"><label><input type="radio" name="lang" value="german" disabled>German</label></div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btnSearch">Search</button>
```

and the javascript:

---

```
$("#form_search").submit(function(){    

  $('#btnSearch').hide();

  var keyword = $('#keyword').val(); keyword = $.trim(keyword);
  //console.log("keyword: "+keyword);

  var timeRange = $("input[type='radio'][name='timeRange']:checked").val();  
  // transform timeRange to unixtime
  var currentTimeStamp = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000); // current browser unix timestamp in seconds  
  if (timeRange == '24h') {timeRangeUnix = currentTimeStamp - 24*3600} // 1 hour = 3600 seconds 
  if (timeRange == 'week') {timeRangeUnix = currentTimeStamp - 7*24*3600} // 1 hour = 3600 seconds
  if (timeRange == 'month') {timeRangeUnix = currentTimeStamp - 30*24*3600} // 1 hour = 3600 seconds
  if (timeRange == 'quarter') {timeRangeUnix = currentTimeStamp - 90*24*3600}
  if (timeRange == 'semi') {timeRangeUnix = currentTimeStamp - 180*24*3600}   
  // console.log("timeRange: "+timeRange);

  var lang = $("input[type='radio'][name='lang']:checked").val();
  // console.log("lang: "+lang);


  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/searchEngine/search.php',
            data: {
                keyword: keyword,
                timeRange: timeRange,
                timeRangeUnix: timeRangeUnix,
                lang: lang,
            },
  });  


});
```

---

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache on Firefox? Could be it's caching some old code.

Comment: _the call to search.php is not properly executed (i.e. marked in red)_ - what is the status code (and message) of the response?